# How does JavaScript interpret indexing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
function highlightRow(searchRow) 
{                       
      if(searchRow != null)
      {
         var oRows = document.getElementById('Table').getElementsByTagName('tr');
         //use row number to highlight the correct HTML row.
         var lastTwo = searchRow;
         lastTwo = lastTwo.slice(-2); //extract last two digits         

         oRows[lastTwo].style.background="#90EE90";
       }       
}
```

I got paging off 100 rows.

When searchRow returns 55, I highlight row 55.
When searchRow returns 177, I highlight row 77, hence the slice function.

Now the issue:
When searchRow returns 03 or 201, the indexing on oRows[] does not work.

Why is this?

To confuse me more when I hard coding "03" it does work:

```
oRows[03].style.background="#90EE90";
```

Any insight into how this works?

Does jQuery have this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: `jQuery` **is** JavaScript, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with a string currently, you need an integer here, like this:

```
oRows[parseInt(lastTwo, 10)].style.background = "#90EE90";
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ebqdh/).

To do an accurate test to see it in action you'll see this works:

```
oRows[03].style.background="#90EE90";
```

But *this* (what's actually happening now) doesn't:

```
oRows["03"].style.background="#90EE90";
```